# Ansible conditions with sequence order (A-Z)

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using AWX and we are using CMDB inventory which contains hell of a information per hosts:  I need help in sorting this "ptseq: A" (order is A-Z), so A will go first then B, then C and D. or reverse order will also help.

```
---
all:
  children:
    no_dns:
      hosts: {}
    no_fqdn:
      hosts: {}
  hosts:
    actualhostname1:
      pd: '2022-01-03'
      pt: '02:00'
      ptt '16:00'
      env: 'PRD'
      hap: null
      ptseq: A
      pwin: '01'
    actualhostname2: 
      pd: '2022-03-12'
      pt: '02:00'
      ptt '16:00'
      env: 'QA'
      hap: null
      ptseq: A
      pwin: '01'
    actualhostname3: 
      pd: '2022-02-22'
      pt: '02:00'
      ptt '16:00'
      env: 'Dev'
      hap: null
      ptseq: A
      pwin: '01'
```

My requirement consists of many conditions (all conditions MUST met).

pd, pt, env, ptseq (order) as  per inventory file, when conditions are met then run it on inventory_hostname in groups['hosts']

```
When:
  - inventory_pd == ansible_date_time.date and (inventory_pt == ansible_date_time.time or inventory_pt == '16:00')
  - inventory_env == 'PRD' or inventory_env=='DEV' or inventory_env=='NP'  
  - inventory_hostname in groups['hosts']
  - inventory_ptseq [A,B,C,D,E,F] ---> This is where i need help...
```

Order must be (A-Z), so we can do things on ptseq Host A, then B, then C then D and so on and so forth until inventory_pd matching with ansible today's date (ansible_date_time.date)

Can somebody please help me complete this logic?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Even if your question is very vague and the given example or snippet do not help to (re)produce the problem you are running it, I'll try to answer a part of your question which I've understand.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you like to execute certain tasks on a group of hosts, based on a sequence tag (`ptseq`) in your inventory and other conditions.

> when conditions are met then run it on `inventory_hostname in groups['hosts']`

According the provided `inventory.yml` file

```
ansible-inventory -i inventory.yml --graph
@all:
  |--@no_dns:
  |--@no_fqdn:
  |--@ungrouped:
  |  |--actualhostname1
  |  |--actualhostname2
  |  |--actualhostname3
```

there is no group `hosts`, but `all` or `ungrouped`. By the way, your sample `inventory.yml` has a syntax error in `ptt`, a missing colon (`:`), therefore I've removed that line for testing.

Since your are already mentioned a sequence from `A` to `F`, [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html) should provide the expected behavior.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Show certain hostvars value(s)
    debug:
      msg: "Sequence: {{ ptseq }}"
    when:
      - env == 'PRD' or env == 'QA' or env == 'Dev'
      - inventory_hostname in groups['ungrouped']
      - ptseq == item
    with_items: [A, B, C, D, E, F]
```

A call of

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml sequence_run.yml
```

will result into an output of

```
TASK [Show certain hostvars value(s)] ******
ok: [actualhostname2] => (item=A) =>
  msg: 'Sequence: A'
ok: [actualhostname3] => (item=A) =>
  msg: 'Sequence: A'
ok: [actualhostname1] => (item=A) =>
  msg: 'Sequence: A'
```

Please take note that within that run the execution order of the hosts was `[2, 3, 1]` and may change for every run.